# Storing class names in database to mimic a design pattern - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I was looking for implementing strategy design pattern in one of my project which is on rails. Basically I have to call methods on objects that are differentiated by a single field in the database, and this difference will ensure different method behavior.

After some study, I found that ruby rarely requires design patterns and that it uses the duck-typing. Now to achieve the same affect, I am thinking about storing class names in the database and call the methods of that class when required. Like this,

```
duckOne = Duck.find(id)
duckOne[:className].fly(duckOne) #This scenario is same as Class.fly,but class is coming from db

duckTwo = Duck.find(id)
duckTwo[:className].fly(duckTwo) #Similar to above, just a different class from database
```

Is there a better way to do it? And is this approach correct?

Comment: Another approach of this is defined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570611/cheat-sheet-for-all-design-patterns-implemented-in-ruby), have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, from what you've described, I think you're looking for [Single Table Inheritance (STI)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) (you may have to scroll to find the info).

With STI you use one database table to represent multiple classes that derive from the same superclass. Rails uses a column called `type` to know which class to interpret the db row as.

You can still use the `find` method on the superclass to find all kinds of subclassing models.

For example:

```
class Bird < ActiveRecord::Base
  def quack
    "quack"
  end
end

class Duck < Bird
  def quack
    "foo"
  end
end

class Goose < Bird
  def quack
    "bar"
  end
end

duck = Duck.create
goose = Goose.create

Bird.find(duck.id).quack
# => "foo"
Bird.find(goose.id).quack
# => "bar"
```

Comment: That is a possible solution, but it does not fit my scenario completely. I stored the classname in the database, fetched it, did `className.constantize` and used className as a class  `className.fly` super simple!

Comment: Please explain how this solution doesn't fit your "question" (which seems to have been more like an invitation for discussion). I think STI is a good match for implementing some kind of variation of behaviour depending on some data in a db, especially if this pertains to objects that reside in the same table. Using inheritance is a good way of modeling this in an Object Oriented context.

Comment: Granted, if you want to share this strategy pattern over several models, some of which don't use the same db table, you'd be better off doing some variant of what you did, perhaps abstracting it out into a module.